# Spring security - check authentication only in 1 endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

I have to following configuration:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private ActuatorProperties actuatorProperties;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
            .withUser(actuatorProperties.getUser())
            .password(actuatorProperties.getPassword())
            .roles("ACTUATOR");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasRole("ACTUATOR")
            .and().httpBasic();
    }
}
```

As you can see I would like to secure only the actuators endpoint and make other application endpoints public. But when any Basic auth is passed it is also validated (401 returned when any other basic auth is provided that does not match to actuator). In my business case I will always have any basic auth header, and I would like to ignore it (simply pass) when it is not actuator.

I also tried things like:

```java
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasRole("ACTUATOR")
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .and().httpBasic();
    }
```

But it also does not work.

Stack:

- Java 17
- Spring boot 2.7.12

Update:
I made a version that actually works as I want, but I'm still looking for more "elegant version"

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring()
           .regexMatchers("^(?!/actuator).*$");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**")
            .hasRole("ACTUATOR")
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Comment: The default implementation of the basic auth filter validates the header if present. The filter doesn't know the authorisation rules. Authentication is always applied before authorisation. If you want to change it, you have to write your own basic auth filter.

Comment: I also thought so at the moment, in order to avoid it, I adopted a form with an ignored path.

Answer (score 0):

You were close but this should work for your use case:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasRole("ACTUATOR") 
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }
```

Comment: Still getting unathorized in other requests (not actuator endpoints)

Comment: In other words, only actuator can make successful request that is passed by spring security

Comment: for development purpose you can chain the following methods to the end (after httpBasic() ) : `.and().csrf().disable();`

Comment: well yes, it may look a bit more clearly

Comment: in my example I didn’t add that piece of code, and if you add that it should work as expected